# Selection of K elements of given ranks

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

Given a procedure/function

$Select(S,r)$ - which selects element of rank r from set S
which uses at most $|S|. constant$ comparisons

We design another function $Multiselect(S,R)$
with $R =\{r_1<r_2<...<r_k\}$
returns $X =\{x_1<x_2<...<x_k\}$  such that rank of $x_i$ is $r_i$

What is the minimum no of comparisons for this function?

From Wikipedia I found the upper bound for it -
[image: upper bound]

But while utilising this for deriving the answer I got it totally messed up!
I tried using algorithm to utilise Select(S,r) repeatedly each time
each time decreasing the search space by logn  ... but I guess the answer could be found
in a more concise mathematical way.

By the way, answer given was - $constant.|S|(1+logR)$

Comment: I don't understand this upper bound, what is $t$ there? If there is an upper bound so there should have been an algorithm. The algorithm you want is simple. As a hint, find out what does $|S|.\log |R|$ suggests about a candidate algorithm?

Comment: The expression $O(|S|.constant)$ is redundant - big O notation already includes the constant, so $O(|S|)$ would have been enough. Similarly, $constant.|S|(1+\log R)$ can be replaced with $O(|S|(1+\log R))$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus- Sorry for the redundant O() . I added it by mistake. Correctly edited above.

Comment: @MahmoudAlimohamadi- check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Lower_bounds
for your confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Find first the element of rank $r_{(k+1)/2}$, and split the list accordingly into two parts $S_1,S_2$ satisfying $|S_1| + |S_2| = |S|$. Now repeat.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus-Are you suggesting a partition around pivot (element of rank $r_{(k+1)/2}$ ) and using divide and conquer to left and right halves.. to get a quicksort like nlogn time? Please clarify.

Comment: That's exactly what I am suggesting, though the analysis is not the one you do for quicksort.

Comment: You have given me the crux move!! Thanks a lot! 
Sorry couldn't vote up for 6 reputation.